# POST requests python html response not rendering

Tags: python, post, python-requests

Is the html on this site scrap-able? 
http://www.customs.go.jp/toukei/srch/indexe.htm?M=03&P=1,2,,,,,,,,1,0,2018,0,5,0,2,271111,,,,,,,,,,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,50

In Chrome Dev Tools Network settings, under Docs, 7 htm docs load, all of which except one are GET requests. The one POST request response contains the data which is in html format (this file is called JCWSV03) and this is the data that I want to access. Unfortunately, when I run the request, I get different html than that which is displayed in the web page.

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests as rq
import urllib.request

url = 'http://www.customs.go.jp/toukei/srch/indexe.htm?M=01&P=1,2,,,,,,,,1,0,2017,0,3,0,2,271111000,,,,,,,,,,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,50'
sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')
soup = bs(sauce, 'lxml')

r2 = rq.post(url) 
soup, r2.text
```

This also does not work:

```
url2 = 'http://www.customs.go.jp/toukei/srch/jccht00p.htm'
parameters = {'Referer' : 'http://www.customs.go.jp/toukei/srch/jccht03e.htm?&P=1,2,,,,,,,,1,0,2018,0,5,0,2,271111,,,,,,,,,,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,50',
'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36'}
r3 = rq.post(url, params = parameters)
r3.text
```

The html that is rendered is this:

```
(<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
 <meta content="Copyright (C) Ministry of Finance, The Japanese Government" name="copyright"/>
 <meta content="NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW" name="robots"/>
 <meta content="text/css" http-equiv="Content-Style-Type"/>
 <link href="jcc.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
 <title>Trade Statistics ( Search ) :Trade Statistics of Japan Ministry of Finance</title>
 </head>
 <script language="JavaScript" src="display/jccjs00me.js"></script>
 <script language="JavaScript">
    <!--
        window.onerror=null;
    //-->
    </script>
 <body><noscript>
        Unless it turns ON the Javascript function of a browser, search in a site cannot be performed.
    </noscript>
 <frameset cols="*">
 <frame name="FR_M_INFO" src="tope.htm" title="TopPage"/>
 </frameset>
 </body></html>,
 'ï»¿<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">\r\n<html lang="en">\r\n\t<head>\r\n\t\t<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">\r\n\t\t<meta name="copyright" content="Copyright (C) Ministry of Finance, The Japanese Government">\r\n\t\t<meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW">\r\n\t\t<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">\r\n\t\t<link href="jcc.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">\r\n\t\t<title>Trade Statistics ( Search ) :Trade Statistics of Japan Ministry of Finance</title>\t\t\r\n\t</head>\r\n\t\r\n\t<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" SRC="display/jccjs00me.js"></SCRIPT>\r\n\t<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">\r\n\t<!--\r\n\t\twindow.onerror=null;\r\n\t//-->\r\n\t</SCRIPT>\r\n\t\r\n\t<noscript>\r\n\t\tUnless it turns ON the Javascript function of a browser, search in a site cannot be performed.\r\n\t</noscript>\r\n\t\r\n\t<FRAMESET COLS="*">\r\n\t\t<FRAME NAME="FR_M_INFO" SRC="tope.htm" title="TopPage">\r\n\t</FRAMESET>\r\n</html>\r\n')
```

Please provide guidance !!
(my ultimate aim so to parse the html is bs4 and into pandas; loop over time)

Comment: have you tried using a headless browser like selenium? looks like this site has protections in place so that you can't easily scrape it without using a browser.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I have and I get the following response in python (using find element by xpath): no such element: Unable to locate element:

Comment: hmm, you're right, this is a really tough one. sorry I can't help! I'll wait the required 2 days and then add a bounty on this question if it's still not answered...would love to see a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a "CSV-download" button which produces this POST request. Duplicate the request with Curl and parse the CSV data:

```
POST /JCWSV03/servlet/JCWSV03 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.customs.go.jp
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1327
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: http://www.customs.go.jp
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
DNT: 1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://www.customs.go.jp/JCWSV03/servlet/JCWSV03
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: JSESSIONID=UBNQ8NK54PAUN3QUGUN5R3H2IK3QJJ9H7Q8DQ3VJV805T740E70SKKJ4DLI02000A8000000.JCWSV03_001; visid_incap_763612=S8FIHQm2Tgap/mXyryhoy+7RPlsAAAAAQUIPAAAAAACi+fyzQ2Gk1dOZsySNYdbt; incap_ses_208_763612=IwFUalbIKRMxrKSSFPjiAu/RPlsAAAAAZNe3OqD0RhBl1jCtr3682w==
```

If you'd like help with doing this in Python with Curl, please post a comment and I'll put that together

Comment: In Network settings, I copied the JCWSV03 as cURL (bash) and inserted to https://curl.trillworks.com/# to generate python POST request. Did I understand your instructions?  I am now able to see the html but not the CSV.

Answer (score 0):

Boo ya!:

```
import requests

cookies = {
    'JSESSIONID': 'V4LKVAGE723K5PGBRA8AVENT943QJJ9H7Q8DQ3RF9AKFUKHMQMVTKJJKD1I020005K000000.JCWSV03_001',
    'visid_incap_763612': 'vh9PZJxzSX+IQrGov+h+4xvvBFsAAAAAQUIPAAAAAACfECPoFSsLL9R6RNgb2BNn',
    'incap_ses_677_763612': 'S7ABVEJemmrXkVaexDBlCYKiPVsAAAAAZdhOPF1KvRtJcnKmfT3GRA==',
    '___utmvmOKuDywS': 'rKJenOqgmrg',
    '___utmvbOKuDywS': 'sZe XmcOOalV: ltS',
}

headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'Origin': 'http://www.customs.go.jp',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Referer': 'http://www.customs.go.jp/toukei/srch/jccht00p.htm',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,en-CA;q=0.8',
}

data = [
  ('CW_SEARCHID', 'JCCHT03S'),
  ('CW_JAPANKBN', '2'),
  ('CW_IMPKBN', '2'),
  ('CW_CARGOKBN', ''),
  ('CW_SUMKBN', ''),
  ('CW_SPCODE', ''),
  ('CW_SPNAME', ''),
  ('CW_YMSORTKBN', ''),
  ('CW_SISUKBN', ''),
  ('CW_SENKIKBN', ''),
  ('CW_HKKBN', ''),
  ('CW_YMKBN', '1'),
  ('CW_KI', ''),
  ('CW_SYY', '2017'),
  ('CW_EYY', ''),
  ('CW_SMM', '2'),
  ('CW_EMM', ''),
  ('CW_HSKBN', '2'),
  ('CW_HSCODE', '271111'),
  ('CW_HSCODE', ''),
  ('CW_HSCODE', ''),
  ('CW_HSCODE', ''),
  ('CW_HSCODE', ''),
  ('CW_HSCODE', ''),
  ('CW_HSCODE', ''),
  ('CW_HSCODE', ''),
  ('CW_HSCODE', ''),
  ('CW_HSCODE', ''),
  ('CW_HSNAME', ''),
  ('CW_HSNAME', ''),
  ('CW_HSNAME', ''),
  ('CW_HSNAME', ''),
  ('CW_HSNAME', ''),
  ('CW_HSNAME', ''),
  ('CW_HSNAME', ''),
  ('CW_HSNAME', ''),
  ('CW_HSNAME', ''),
  ('CW_HSNAME', ''),
  ('CW_KUNIKBN', '1'),
  ('CW_KUNICODE', ''),
  ('CW_KUNICODE', ''),
  ('CW_KUNICODE', ''),
  ('CW_KUNICODE', ''),
  ('CW_KUNICODE', ''),
  ('CW_KUNICODE', ''),
  ('CW_KUNICODE', ''),
  ('CW_KUNICODE', ''),
  ('CW_KUNICODE', ''),
  ('CW_KUNICODE', ''),
  ('CW_KUNINAME', ''),
  ('CW_KUNINAME', ''),
  ('CW_KUNINAME', ''),
  ('CW_KUNINAME', ''),
  ('CW_KUNINAME', ''),
  ('CW_KUNINAME', ''),
  ('CW_KUNINAME', ''),
  ('CW_KUNINAME', ''),
  ('CW_KUNINAME', ''),
  ('CW_KUNINAME', ''),
  ('CW_ZMKBN', ''),
  ('CW_ZMCODE', ''),
  ('CW_ZMCODE', ''),
  ('CW_ZMCODE', ''),
  ('CW_ZMCODE', ''),
  ('CW_ZMCODE', ''),
  ('CW_ZMCODE', ''),
  ('CW_ZMCODE', ''),
  ('CW_ZMCODE', ''),
  ('CW_ZMCODE', ''),
  ('CW_ZMCODE', ''),
  ('CW_ZMNAME', ''),
  ('CW_ZMNAME', ''),
  ('CW_ZMNAME', ''),
  ('CW_ZMNAME', ''),
  ('CW_ZMNAME', ''),
  ('CW_ZMNAME', ''),
  ('CW_ZMNAME', ''),
  ('CW_ZMNAME', ''),
  ('CW_ZMNAME', ''),
  ('CW_ZMNAME', ''),
  ('CW_MEISAICNT', '200'),
]

response = requests.post('http://www.customs.go.jp/JCWSV03/servlet/JCWSV03', data=data)

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
soup = bs(response.text, 'html.parser')
country = [x.text for x in soup.find_all('td', 'left_sTotal')[0::3]]
quantity = [x.text for x in soup.find_all('td', 'sTotal')[1::6]]
value = [x.text for x in soup.find_all('td', 'sTotal')[2::6]]
total_list = [list(x) for x in zip(country,quantity,value)]

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(total_list, columns = ('country', 'quantity', 'value'))
df.head()
```